# SSD based on ResNet-101 doesn't improve over SSD-VGGNet

Tags: object-detection, deep-learning

I am training a SSD model for detecting mobile cranes.
The training dataset contains 1,000 images and test set over 400 images.
About 200 epochs gave mAP 83%, but my target is 90%.
So I trained SSD-ResNet-101 and it gave less accuracy.

I assume that it is because ResNet-101 is too deep for the size of my dataset.
I consider using ResNet-50 and Inception.
But I don't have time to experiment all the models with different parameter settings.

Is there anyone who has experience in this direction?
Any advice is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes as you said the dataset is likely to be too small for that amount of layers and the model is likely to overfit. I would try with shallower architectures. Inception and ResNet are better for fine tuning in your case.

Comment: Thank you, @FrancescoPegoraro. Do you mean ResNet-50?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the best way to increase performance to increase training data and to train longer.